# Django refresh_from_db for ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to use refresh_from_db and automatically propagate it on ForeignKey ?

**model.py:**

```
class TestItemModel(models.Model):
  value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  relies_on_item = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True )
```

**shell:**

```
>>> end_product = TestItemModel(value=1)
>>> end_product.save()
>>> container_product = TestItemModel(value=10,relies_on_item=end_product)
>>> container_product.save()
>>> end_product.pk
12
>>> end_product_for_update=TestItemModel.objects.get(pk=12)
>>> end_product_for_update.value = 4
>>> end_product_for_update.save()
>>> container_product.relies_on_item.value
1
>>> container_product.refresh_from_db()
>>> container_product.relies_on_item.value
1
```

The value returned at this point is still the initial one. Is there an option to make refresh_from_db automatically cascade on elements referenced by ForeignKey?

It is possible to do it by explicitly using refresh_from_db on the referenced item - shown below. But I would like to only have to do  refresh_from_db on container_product itself.

**shell (continued):**

```
>>> container_product.relies_on_item.refresh_from_db()
>>> container_product.relies_on_item.value
4
```

Comment: A cascade on a self referencing model. That would easily result in a recursion loop. I guess this is why it is not implemented as cascade. If you need it, you have to add it yourself including prevention of infinite recursion.

Comment: Which version of django you are using ?

Comment: @itzmeontv django 1.10.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK In django, Till now `refresh_from_db` will not update data for relational fields.It only check whether relation is removed or not. But you can do like (as you did).

```
for i in container_product._meta.concrete_fields:
    if i.is_relation:
        getattr(container_product, i.name).refresh_from_db()
```

OR override `refresh_from_db`

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    def refresh_from_db(self, using=None, fields=None):
        super(Mymodel, self).refresh_from_db(using=None, fields=None)
        for i in self._meta.concrete_fields:
            if i.is_relation and getattr(self, i.name):
                getattr(self, i.name).refresh_from_db()
```

Comment: Thank you that last one does the job. I had to add a check for the getattr to not be None. That one does not prevent infinite recursion but that's not a problem for my particular use case.

Comment: Too bad the django doc doesn't mention that `refresh_from_db` doesn't update relational fields (as reverse OneToOne for example). I've spent a day trying to understand why my tests were failing!

Comment: Pay attention that the current implementation does not refresh CACHED reverse FK, you want to null them by iterating over `_meta.related_objects`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, what if the referenced FK object also has FK objects of its own? This implementation  only works for 1-level of "nestedness" / depth, right? Additionally, I guess a small improvement for the class implementation could be retaining `getattr(self, i.name)` in a variable so that `getattr` is not called twice.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to retrieve instance again from DB without using `refresh_from_db`.

```
instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
```